# Загрузить несколько файлов с помощью FileREader

Tags: javascript

Уже несколько часов "бьюсь" над поставленным вопросом. С загрузкой одного файла проблем нет. А вот когда пытаюсь загрузить несколько  - загружается (считывается) только последний, а остальные "проскакиевает".
html

```
<form>
<input type="file" multiple>
</form>
<button type="button" id="btn">Принять</button>
```

js

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var input = document.forms[0][0];
btn.onclick = function(){
        if (input.files.length > 0){
            for (var i=0; i<input.files.length; i++) {
            var read = new FileReader();
            read.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
            read.onload = function(){
                console.log(read.readyState);
                console.log(read.result);
                }
            }
        } else {
            alert("Сделайте выбор")
        }
};
```

Я так понял, что событие `onload` генерируется, когда будет загружен последний файл. А как отловить загрузку всех предыдущих файлов?

Comment: Вообщем, по всей видимости, все дело в асинхронности. Процесс чтения файла выделил в отдельную функцию и в цикле запускал эту функцию, передавая в нее файл. Все заработало. 
Но вот на счет дубликата вопроса...у меня есть сомнения. Перед тем как задать вопрос - гуглил. Вообще, нигде ни слова о сути проблемы (на русскоязычных сайтах). При таком подходе, как мне кажется, 50% вопросов можно считать повторением. Но за наводку, спасибо!

Comment: Дубликат 100%. В цикле ты создаешь функцию, которая замыкает значение переменной `read`. В момент когда функция будет выполняться цикл уже закончится и значением переменной read будет значение на последней итерации цикла. Используешь любое решение из вопроса дубликата, например `let read = ... ` и все заработает